# How to search using session with multiple table with where caluse using Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.8

How to do this?

**This code is working **

```
    $posts = NewJob::with(['client_info','office_info'])
      ->orderBy('won', 'desc')
      ->where('progress' , 'forwarded')
      ->where('won', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
      ->paginate(5);
```

========================================================================
But when I added more where clause then displaying the blank results.

```
  $posts = NewJob::with(['client_info','office_info'])
      ->orderBy('won', 'desc')
      ->where('progress' , 'forwarded')
      ->where('won', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
      ->where('proj_name', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
      ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: these 3 where conditions means that it should be matched, instead you can use whereOr conditions.

Comment: In simple words, it means `AND` condition, but if you are trying these conditions then it means you have to first check if any record or value in request is not empty, otherwise it will not show data.

Comment: Oh that's why it shows me blnak result...

Comment: Yes exactly, and another thing, you can simply pass `with('client_info','office_info')` without the array notations.

Comment: Then how to use OR condition?

Comment: ->where('won', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
         ->where('client_infos.name', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')  Can u show me the code with or condition...

Comment: See the answer, this might you need.

Comment: did you get the idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can do it.
You can also use one orWhere condition instead of two, according to your need.

```
$posts = NewJob::with('client_info','office_info')
  ->orderBy('won', 'desc')
  ->where('progress' , 'forwarded')
  ->where('won', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
  ->orWhere('proj_name', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
  ->paginate(5);
```

For joins mean to say relations you can do it something like this.
I have written the code for one of your model, you can do it for other models same like this, and also you can use the closure function in `with()` function as well. Also you can use `orWhereHas` on different models as well.

```
$posts = NewJob::whereHas('client_info', function($query){
      $query->where('something','is_something'); //query conditions on other table
      $query->orWhere('something','is_something');
  })
  ->orderBy('won', 'desc')
  ->where('progress' , 'forwarded')
  ->where('won', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
  ->orWhere('proj_name', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
  ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: with orWhere shows me the error Trying to get property of non-object. of client_info and office_info object.

Comment: `$request->session()->get('search')` have you put search in a session variable ?

Comment: have you `dd($request->session()->get('search'));` what it gives you show me please.

Comment: with where clause its working but with orWhere not working and ofcourse i used the sarch in a session variable.

Comment: and have you removed the `[ ]` from `with();` ?

Comment: I got the problem when session got deleted then it shows me error... Now i will solve it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Okay you welcome, and ofcourse if you have deleted something from the session, then you will updated the new session in the same variable again.

Comment: ->orWhere('othertable.columnname', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')    How to implement in laravel?

Comment: are you talking about joins ?

Comment: Yes i am taking about joins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199663/discussion-between-devraj-and-akhtar-munir).